# How could Python functions of a library be made available as Bash commands?

Tags: python, bash, function, interface, command

Let's say I have a large Python library of functions and I want these functions (or some large number of them) to be available as commands in Bash.

First, disregarding Bash command options and arguments, how could I get a function of a Python file containing a number of functions to run using a single word Bash command? I do not want to have the functions available via commands of a command 'suite'. So, let's say I have a function called `zappo` in this Python file (say, called `library1.py`). I would want to call this function using a single-word Bash command like `zappo`, *not* something like `library1 zappo`.

Second, how could options and arguments be handled? I was thinking that a nice way could be to capture all of the options and arguments of the Bash command and then use them within the Python functions using `docopt` parsing *at the function level```.

Comment: Do you know the names of all the functions? Or do you want `bash` to start searching through python files to find one which has commands in it?

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your thoughts on this. What I am inclined towards is running a Python script which changes the Bash environment such that a defined set of functions within the Python script become available in the Bash environment using single commands.

Comment: Its common to write short scripts to do this. `zappo` could be a python script that imports `library1` and calls the function. Is that okay or part of the forbidden "command suite"?

Comment: The canonical way is to create CLI scripts that use `argparse`. If your code is inside a package, `setuptools` can automatically create CLI `entry_points` to your functions.

Comment: @d3pd: You can't modify the bash environment from a subshell. You could, of course, use a python program to generate a bash script file, but you'd still need to arrange for that to be source'd in your bash initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the answer might not be as simple as you hope. No matter what you do, you're going to have to create something in your bash shell for each function you want to run. However, you could have a Python script generate aliases stored in a file which gets sourced.

Here's the basic idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import __main__ #<-- This allows us to call methods in __main__
import inspect #<-- This allows us to look at methods in __main__

########### Function/Class.Method Section ##############
# Update this with functions you want in your shell    #
########################################################
def takesargs():
    #Just an example that reads args
    print(str(sys.argv))
    return

def noargs():
    #and an example that doesn't
    print("doesn't take args")
    return
########################################################

#Make sure there's at least 1 arg (since arg 0 will always be this file)
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #This fetches the function info we need to call it
    func = getattr(__main__, str(sys.argv[1]), None)
    if callable(func):
        #Actually call the function with the name we received
        func()
    else:
        print("No such function")
else:
    #If no args were passed to this function, just output a list of aliases for this script that can be appended to .bashrc or similar.
    funcs = inspect.getmembers(__main__, predicate=inspect.isfunction)
    for func in funcs:
        print("alias {0}='./suite.py {0}'".format(func[0]))
```

Obviously, if you're using methods in a class instead of functions in main, change references from `__main__` to your class, and change predicate in the inspect to `inspect.ismethod`. Also, you probably would want to use absolute paths for the aliases, etc.

Sample output:

```
~ ./suite.py
alias noargs='./suite.py noargs'
alias takesargs='./suite.py takesargs'

~ ./suite.py > ~/pyliases

~ echo ". ~/pyliases" >> ~/.bashrc

~ . ~/.bashrc

~ noargs
doesn't take args

~ takesargs blah
['./suite.py', 'takesargs', 'blah']
```

If you use the method I've suggested above, you can actually have your .bashrc run `~/suite.py > ~/pyliases` before it sources the aliases from the file. Then your environment gets updated every time you log in/start a new terminal session. Just edit your python function file, and then `. ~/.bashrc` and the functions will be available.